# store list of arbitrary methods in C++

Tags: c++, containers, pointer-to-member

The intention in pseudo code:

```
T magicContainer;

magicContainer.push(method1);
magicContainer.push(method2);
...
magicContainer.push(methodN);

magicContainer.loop(i) {
    magicContainer[i].call(...);
}
```

Now `method1`, `method2`, ... shall have arbitrary signatures - I would then claim, that this is simply not possible in C++. Explanation: whether you use old-school ways like void pointers or fancy boost::any you will always have to keep track of the function signature type somewhere. Still I want to ask: what are the closest, most elegant solutions for this scenario?

Comment: `"most elegant solutions for this scenario"` ... 1) Avoid it altogether. Why do you need this?

Comment: What are you ellipsing over in call(...)? If each function could have a different signature, how could you treat them all equivalently?

Comment: You can use `std::bind` to supply the appropriate parameters, then store the resulting `std::function` instances in a homogenous container.

Comment: In c++ there is no "undefined" value like javascript has it. That means you must know the type of the parameter when you call a method in order to crate a meaningful value for a parameter. Please give more context where you need this.

Comment: @dlf: you are right, at "call(...)" the programer has to know what to pass, but Im thinking of variadic methods so some flexibility is meaningful.

Comment: @Zotta: you are right as well. I recon the benefit of such a pattern is very limited in C++. It's mostly about wrapping and grouping methods not by class and not by type but some more "human" logic. Scenario example: group all "getter" methods from a set of classes (they ll have different signature) to let another programer easily loop through all of them without "collecting" them himself.

Comment: @OMGtechy: I recon, but see answer for Zotta above.

Comment: @BenVoigt: this wont do I fear, each std::function will be unique through its templates so again you need a typeless container like boost::any.